# How to filter out the rows that do not start with digit (CSV, PySpark). Edited: Contain only with number

Tags: python, pyspark, data-cleaning

[CSV File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_bjkZFWtSdnAJia2tV7DDe2fj7riTous/view?usp=sharing)

In the df a column in there has some rows which do not start with digit, i want them to delete, i tried some code below but they dont work

```
import re
df = sqlContext.read.csv("/FileStore/tables/mtmedical_V6-16623.csv", header='true', inferSchema="true")

df.show()

import pyspark.sql.functions as f
w=df.filter(df['_c0'].isdigit()) #error1
w=df.filter(df['_c0'].startswith(('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'))) #error2
w.show()
```

errors:

```
'Column' object is not callable #no1
py4j.Py4JException: Method startsWith([class java.util.ArrayList]) does not exist #no2
```

here is the table, you can  see that the row below row 7 in the column '_c0' does not start with digit, how can i delete such rows?

```
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|                 _c0|         description|   medical_specialty|                 age|              gender|sample_name (What has been done to patient = Treatment)|       transcription|            keywords|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|                   1| A 23-year-old wh...| Allergy / Immuno...|                  23|              female|                                     Allergic Rhinitis |SUBJECTIVE:,  Thi...|allergy / immunol...|
|                   2| Consult for lapa...|          Bariatrics|                null|                male|                                    Laparoscopic Gas...|PAST MEDICAL HIST...|bariatrics, lapar...|
|                   3| Consult for lapa...|          Bariatrics|                  42|                male|                                    Laparoscopic Gas...|"HISTORY OF PRESE...| at his highest h...|
|                   4| 2-D M-Mode. Dopp...| Cardiovascular /...|                null|                null|                                    2-D Echocardiogr...|2-D M-MODE: , ,1....|cardiovascular / ...|
|                   5|  2-D Echocardiogram| Cardiovascular /...|                null|                male|                                    2-D Echocardiogr...|1.  The left vent...|cardiovascular / ...|
|                   6| Morbid obesity. ...|          Bariatrics|                  30|                male|                                    Laparoscopic Gas...|PREOPERATIVE DIAG...|bariatrics, gastr...|
|                   7| Liposuction of t...|                null|                null|                null|                                                   null|                null|                null|
|", Bariatrics,31,...|       1.  Deformity| right breast rec...|2.  Excess soft t...| anterior abdomen...|                                   3.  Lipodystrophy...|POSTOPERATIVE DIA...|       1.  Deformity|
|                   8|  2-D Echocardiogram| Cardiovascular /...|                null|                male|                                    2-D Echocardiogr...|2-D ECHOCARDIOGRA...|cardiovascular / ...|
```

Comment: Could you add your table in CSV format?

Comment: @DavidScott, `csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'format'`and btw it is already in csv format `sqlContext.read.csv`

Comment: try `df.filter((F.split("_c0","")[0]).isin([x for x in range(1,10)]))`

Comment: @leocleo I meant could you add it to your question so I can use your example data without having to convert the format of the list as you have provided it to us into CSV to test.

Comment: @DavidScott, done, on the top you have the link to see the csv file

Comment: It is not shared.

Comment: @DavidScott, sorry , shared from wrong account, check it now, it should work

Comment: @MohammadMurtazaHashmi, man thank you, it works actually! Appreciate your help

Comment: @MohammadMurtazaHashmi, now i ran into another problem, how to take the rows, that contain **only digits**, if it is a mixture of digits and letters i dont want it, only digits? Appearently some of those broken rows,were starting with digit :/.

Comment: @MohammadMurtazaHashmi, man please, have a look, help me.

Comment: for big data where `df.count()` is not a feasible operation, you could use `df.filter(F.regexp_extract("_c0","\D+",0)=='')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df.filter((f.col('_c0')).isin([x for x in range(1,df.count()+1)]))
```